# How to rotate bitmapimage and use it in drawcontext?

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, kinect, bitmapimage

I'm trying to replace the image of the head, using the kinect but I'm stuck. I already replace it, the problem is, I wanted to rotate it accordingly with the angle of the neck, to be more real. I already tried many solutions and they didn't work, and the reason, I think, is because I'm applying that changes to the bitmapimage and when I load the image to the drawcontext, I'm doing it from the source. 
So the image isn't rotating...  How can I do it using drawingContext? (Btw, do you know some nice source for I learn a little bit more about drawingContexts, Groups, etc? Thanks in advance.
Here's the code:

```
                        Point headPoint = SkeletonPointToColorScreen(joint.Position, sensor);
                    double X = headPoint.X - 50;
                    double Y = headPoint.Y - 60;
                    int AnguloNeck = (int)Math.Round(Angles.AngleBetweenYaxis(skeleton, JointType.ShoulderCenter,
                                JointType.Head), 0);
                    MainWindow.aBraços.headImage.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform() { CenterX = 0.5, CenterY = 0.5, Angle = AnguloNeck };

                    Rect R = new Rect(X, Y, MainWindow.aBraços.headImage.ActualWidth, MainWindow.aBraços.headImage.ActualHeight);

                    drawingContext.DrawImage(MainWindow.aBraços.headImage.Source, R);
```

Comment: DrowingContext has PushTransform method. Did you try it?

Comment: No I didn't, because doing that, I'm actually rotating all the other drawings of that DrawingContext, or am I wrong?
And I only wanted to rotate that headImage..
Well, in all the case I'll try it, just to be sure.. And thanks any way :)

Comment: Don't forget to reset the transformation by pushing identity transform after you paint tour image.